# Is there a verb for making something more "exoteric"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anyone here know of a suitable verb for making something "exoteric"? I am trying to find a word that adequately encapsulates "making an idea more accessible to the broader community." I like the adjective "exoteric" for this, but am wondering if there is a verb that can be used instead.

(Note, I use "make accessible" quite a bit in this sort of situation, which is why I am looking for a succinct verb that I can use instead.)

Comment: 'Ameliorate' isn't quite right. You want a verbal form of 'user-friendly', but 'user befriend' and 'user-friendlify' don't exist.

Comment: 'exoteric' is not very exoteric.

Comment: *Promulgating?*

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How is "ameliorate" related to this question? The definition that I know is "make (something bad or unsatisfactory) better."

Comment: Try the [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ameliorate) definition. To make [something at the moment unsatisfactory] better. Certainly ballpark. Something 'e**s**oteric' is unsatisfactory (from OP's PoV) in that it means _understood by only a few people having a specialist/arcane knowledge/interest_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks.  That is in the ballpark, but it wouldn't be my word of choice for this situation.

Comment: @John B. 'Popularise' obviously fits, and is given in the duplicate. The fact that OP uses 'make accessible' slightly suggests (confusingly to me) a teaching, education context (rather than a general societal context), where 'popularise' wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That makes more sense.  I was thinking about it in a societal context.  Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: I think it's somewhat ironic that here we have a question asking how to make some text more "**accessible**" to the general public, but even here on a site for "language *experts*" there will be an awful lot of people looking up the meaning of the word [**exoteric**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/exoteric). If you're late to the party, I'll save you the trouble: ***intended for or likely to be understood by the general public.***

Comment: While this question is rightly closed as a duplicate, it should be noted that, even though the question that it is a duplicate of asked  about 'making something more broadly known and understood', almost all the answers to it are solely about making something more broadly **known**, and ignore the 'and understood' part of the question. The only answer there that takes into account both components of the question is the same one as given on this page: *popularise*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that is indeed the definition that captures the meaning of the word in the present-day casual use, but it doesn't capture the associations that the word carries from its origins in the religious and philosophical teachings that had esoteric and exoteric versions. The most apt uses of the word are in the contexts in which these associations are illuminating; otherwise one may as well just say 'accessible'.

Comment: @jsw29: My comment included a link to the dictionary definition from which I copied that highlighted text. I just didn't include the caveat ***(especially of a doctrine or mode of speech)***, or the example usage ***an exoteric, literal meaning and an esoteric, inner teaching***. Not to mention their final observation *The opposite of **esoteric*** . Bizarrely, my Google Chrome spell-checker is underlining the word "exoteric" in red every time I write it in a comment, even when that comment includes a link to a dictionary definition thereof! :).

Answer (score 1):

*Please note that **your question is a little vague**, so some of these might have slightly different meanings from the one you intended; I urge you to **carefully read the definitions to ensure that the words are applicable to your context**.*

**"Vulgarize,"** **"popularize,"** **"propagate,"** and many other synonyms would solve your problem.  **Note:** if by "make accessible" you simply mean "to spread an idea," you can use all of these words (and many of their synonyms); if you mean "to make an idea less complicated so the masses can understand," I would use the first two.  To "make [something] exoteric" would be to make it less complicated to teach it to the general public, so I tried to find words with that specific meaning (only "vulgarize" and "popularize" accomplish this—not "propagate").

The applicable definition of "vulgarize" (from [HERE](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/vulgarize) is: **"make commonplace or less subtle or complex."**

The applicable definition of "popularize" (from [HERE](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/popularize) is **"make (something technical, scientific, or academic) accessible or interesting to the general public by presenting it in a readily understandable form."**

The applicable definition of "propagate" (from [HERE](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/propagate) is **"spread and promote (an idea, theory, etc.) widely."**

Comment: *Vulgarize* has some implications that the OP probably wants to avoid (which the quoted definition does not fully bring out); *propagate* doesn't capture the idea of making something easier to understand by the uninitiated, which is the essence of making something more exoteric. *Popularize* is probably the best candidate, except that it implies that the intention is to make the material in question popular (i.e. very widely known), while what the OP has in mind may be only making it accessible to a somewhat wider, but still not very wide, audience.

Comment: @jsw29 I agree with you about "propagate." That is why I included the "note" at the beginning.  Also, you bring up a good point about "vulgarize."  Personally, I would use "popularize" (for the reasons you mentioned).  One thing that I wasn't completely sure about was what Decapitated Soul meant by "make accessible," which was why I tried to find words that meant "make exoteric."  I included "propagate" just in case if they simply meant "to spread an idea."  Thanks for your comment, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As an American, the word *exoteric* was new to me -- I had to look it up -- so much for making things easier.

I would use a word like: simplify, decipher, explain, resolve, clarify for the broader community. If I weren't worried about the pejorative sense, I would use *dumb down*, or even *mansplaining*.

Answer (score 0):

OED

**Popularise/popularize** (v.)

> 2c. *transitive*. **To present (a technical or specialized subject) in a generally intelligible or appealing form. Occasionally intransitive.**

> 1873   J. Earle Philol. Eng. Tongue (ed. 2) xii. 620   *Engaged in the diffusion of knowledge, in popularising history or science.*

> 1991   R. Ashton G. H. Lewes A Life iii. 45   *Lewes, for the first time, gives evidence of his powers of popularizing, of making difficult, even technical, arguments palatable to the layman.*